# Is there an argument that limits the maximum depth of the regression tree to be plotted from rpart.plot?

Tags: r, plot, tree, regression, rpart

My concern about the print size would be the probability of freezing up the computer due to the great depth of the regression trees. So, I would like to limit the size of the printed tree through rpart.plot.

I have tried to identify a specific argument from the rpart.plot-help but I was unsuccessful.
I hope that there is either some parameter or any other way to visualize part of the regression tree.

Comment: It is set through the `control=` argument: `rpart(..., control = rpart.control(maxdepth = 6))`  See `?rpart.control`

Comment: Hello Grothendieck,
My question is regarding rpart.plot.  Since I print the tree graph, the computer may freeze up due to the size of the graph.
I would like to limit the graph size to have a first overview.

Comment: Run `r <- rpart(...)` as shown iin my comment and then `plot(r)` .